# Search and Remove Members from Objects

Tags: arrays, powershell, object

I'm attempting to search an existing object to find (members? is this what they're called?) where the name property is equal to the servername found in a text file (FalsePositiveDevices.txt) and then delete that entire member with all of its properties.

When I run the following there are no errors, but the $global:LimitedSNReportObject still has the members from the false positive list.

**FalsePositiveList Example:**

server1

server2

**global:LimitedSNReportObject Example:**

name,IPAddress,Platform

server1,10.10.10.10,Windows

server3,11.11.11.11,Linux

**Code Example:**

```
$FalsePositiveList = Get-Content 
"C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\FalsePositiveDevices.txt"

foreach ($server in $FalsePositiveList) {
  $global:LimitedSNReportObject |  foreach-object {
    if ($_.name -eq $server) {
        $global:LimitedSNReportObject.psobject.members.remove($_)  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, you're just looking for how to use `Where` statements? You could do `$Global:LimitedSNReportObject = $global:LimitedSNReportObject | Where{$_.name -NotIn $FalsePositiveList}`

Comment: That was exactly it, I didn't know it was that easy. Thank you!

Comment: So that you understand, `Get-Content` returns an array of strings and you want to remove some of those strings (objects) from the array. A member is a 'thing' on an object, eg the objects returned by `Get-Service` have DisplayName, Status, and Stop() members (among many others) specific to those objects.